# Analyze the output of awk by c++filt command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, c++filt

Good day, everyone!
I have a file with a list of inlined c++ functions. I want to c++filt them. But not all the functions of the list are interesting for me, so i use awk sript to get the nessesary functions.

So, the question is, how to combine "c++filt" and "awk" commands in terminal to analyze the output of awk script by "c++filt" command? 
Thanx for every answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk ... | c++filt -t
```

should do (where `...` denotes your awk filter)